# mouseup is not fired after mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery

the mouseup is not activated after mousedown. I'm not sure why. But if I uncomment the line

```
$(this).replaceWith("<div class=" + "'" + $canvas.replace(".", " ") + "'" + "></div>");
```

then the mouseup works normally. Here is the piece of code

```
var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {
       // Painting the map with canvas
        $map_canvas.mousedown(function () {
            var ignoreMouseMove = false;
            mouseDownFired = true;



            $(".map .row div").mousemove(function (e) {

                if (ignoreMouseMove) return;
                //$(this).replaceWith("<div class=" + "'" + $canvas.replace(".", " ") + "'" + "></div>");

                moveCanvas($canvas, e)
            }).mouseup(function () {
                ignoreMouseMove = true;
            });


        });

        var paletteClone = $(document).clone(true);     // bound handler for .palette div

};



var moveCanvas = function ($canvas, e) {
    $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
        left: e.pageX - 30,
        top: e.pageY - 30
    });
};
```

Comment: `.replaceWith` removes `$(".map .row div")` element which `.mouseUp` has been bounded. That is why `.mouseup` is not triggered.

Comment: please provide some html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `mouseup` event to a DOM element which you then replace in the `mousemove` event - the `mouseup` event cannot run because the element is no longer on the page.

An alternative is to bind the `mouseup` event using the `on` function using the parent of `.map .row` - this binds the event to the parent instead so elements which are added still get behaviours as you expect.

```
var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {
   // Painting the map with canvas
    $map_canvas.mousedown(function () {
        var ignoreMouseMove = false;
        mouseDownFired = true;

        $(".map .row").on("mousemove", "div", (function (e) {

            if (ignoreMouseMove) return;

            // this is now OK - event bound to parent 
            $(this).replaceWith("<div class=" + "'" + $canvas.replace(".", " ") + "'" + "></div>");

            moveCanvas($canvas, e)
        }).on("mouseup", "div", function () {
            ignoreMouseMove = true;
        });


    });

    var paletteClone = $(document).clone(true);     // bound handler for .palette div

};



var moveCanvas = function ($canvas, e) {
    $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
        left: e.pageX - 30,
        top: e.pageY - 30
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe i didn't see that